# How to put an Edittext with a correct value, and all the others wrong

Tags: android, android-edittext

My intention is to put an Edittext, and a button below, and when the user put an specific word and click the button, the value is correct, and all the other different words are wrong.. How to identify it with codes?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: http://bit.ly/1ef1e1u

Answer (score 0):

first you create the editText and the button

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

then the rest is easy ..

```
EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String Answer = txt.getText().toString();

Button check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
if(Answer.equals("your word")){
//correct
} else{
//wrong
}
                }
            });
```

we define our edittext and button, then we get the text from the edittext and convert it to a string. after that when our button is clicked we chick if it's equal to something it do ...